# SQL - select parent and child records in an order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, common-table-expression

I got a table which has both question Id and parent question ids in the same table as :

```
QUES_ID | Ques_Txt  | Parent_Ques_Id
--------+-----------+---------+---------------
     97  |  X       | NULL
     101 |  Y       | NULL
     115 |  Z       | NULL
     198 |  A       | 97
     302 |  B       | 97
     151 |  C       | 101
     91  |  D       | 115
   1110  |  E       | 115
   1111  |  F       | 115
```

Now, I want to get a result set as follows in the following order:

```
QUES_ID | Ques_Txt  | Parent_Ques_Id
--------+-----------+---------+---------------
     97  |  X       | NULL
     198 |  A       | 97
     302 |  B       | 97
     101 |  Y       | NULL
     151 |  C       | 101
     115 |  Z       | NULL         
     91  |  D       | 115
   1110  |  E       | 115
   1111  |  F       | 115
```

Having parent question listed right above the child question, I have researched for a similar query but all i found is how to display parent-child records using left joins or CTEs, but not in the order that I'm looking for as in the above table. Can any one help, I'm still learning.

Comment: FYI, this is do-able, but it is a hard problem.

Comment: Two questions, 1) what version of SQL Server? and 2) what is the maximum number of siblings/children with the same parent?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012, A given parent can have a maximum of 4 children based on the data I got

Comment: How many levels of children can there be?  (ex. can their be grand children?)

Comment: No, there will not be any grand children but, one parent can have a maximum  of four children

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick response, much appreciated

Comment: What is the order of the children under a parent? From your sample data it could be either alphabetically by `Ques_Txt` or numerically by `QUES_ID`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using a trick with `coalesce`:

```
select *
from t
order by coalesce(parent_ques_id, ques_id), parent_ques_id, ques_id
```

Sorting logic would be:

1. Sort all parent-child relations one after another (97, 101, 115) `coalesce(parent_ques_id, ques_id)` - assign a parent it's own id (instead of null) to be sorted with his children
2. Make parent appear on top of each group `parent_ques_id` - nulls sort before values in ASC order as default (in SQL Server)
3. Sort children by their id `ques_id`

Comment: This would work if the `ques_id's` were in order, but they aren't.  For example `91` would return before it's parent `115`...

Comment: This only works if this is only one level of parents/children (ie., no grandchildren/grandparents).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing this work correctly: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4iuXtV8qyksbwL6hS45Wy8/1

Comment: @sgeddes see http://rextester.com/NLKY17569 It's better to test it for the database it's supposed to work with, due to different default null handling in order by clause between Postgres and SQL Server.

Comment: Try ORDER BY clause like this: `order by coalesce(parent_ques_id, ques_id), ques_id`.  If there is only one level (ie., no grandparents/grandchildren) then this is a better approach than mine.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I've had this one before, but then 91 would sort before it's parent that has higher id (115) which sgeddes pointed out (thanks), hence the next column to sort by

Comment: @KamilG. -- Nice job!  I should have realized that I was testing in the wrong db... Upvoted!

Comment: @KamilG. Right, OP added it in the comments after I had already started writing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` clause :

```
order by (case when Parent_Ques_Id is null 
               then QUES_ID else Parent_Ques_Id end), Parent_Ques_Id, QUES_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is how I would do it, this version handles up to 99 siblings.  As I said, it's complicated.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        QUES_ID,
        Quest_Txt,
        Parent_Quest_Id,
        --(assumes max 9 siblings)
        RIGHT('0'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Parent_Quest_Id ORDER BY Quest_Txt) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 1) AS [path],
        0 AS level
    FROM Questions
    WHERE Parent_Quest_Id = 0

  UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.QUES_ID,
        t.Quest_Txt,
        t.Parent_Quest_Id,
        [path] +'-'
        --(assumes max 99 siblings)
        + RIGHT('00'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.Parent_Quest_Id ORDER BY t.Quest_Txt) AS VARCHAR(max)), 2),
        level+1
    FROM cte
    JOIN Questions t ON cte.QUES_ID = t.Parent_Quest_Id
)
SELECT
    QUES_ID,
    Quest_Txt,
    Parent_Quest_Id,
    [path]
FROM cte
ORDER BY path
```

Comment: Oops, missed that there's no grandparents/grandchildren.  If that's still true then @KamilG's solution is much simpler and preferred.